# How to use custom fonts in Laravel's blade?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

Basically, I have imported various custom font templates into my `public/fonts` folder. Examples are `Muli`, `Muli-Bold`, `Muli-ExtraBold`. My question now is, how do I call and use these fonts in my blade files?

Comment: I would suggest using cdn. and muli is google font as well so go for CDN instead of hosting those fonts in project.

Comment: but the site im working on requires me to use muli though..

Comment: you can use CDN for all --- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Muli is google font as i send you CDN link, you can add this to your layout file which impact all over the site.

Comment: got it, thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add custom font in lavarel you can add it just like you do in HTML file . You can add in css as:

```
    @font-face { 
font-family: Muli-Bold; src: url('/fonts/Muli-Bold.tff');
 }
```

Or you can include the above code in `blade` using the style tag.

Comment: i get that this is adding it in the project, but how do i call it in my text? say i have <p>This is what i want to be in the font format</p>

Comment: Refer to this site. this might help you a but  https://greatives.ticksy.com/article/5843

Comment: Or you can use cnd and directly import the url of the font you wanna use.. i think that will really impact all over

Answer (score 4):

You can add custom fonts in laravel as like you add in an HTML template. You can add it in `blade` like

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: Muli-Bold;
        src: url('{{ public_path('fonts/Muli-Bold.tff') }}');
    }
</style>
```

And you can add it in any `css` file as :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Muli-Bold;
    src: url('/fonts/Muli-Bold.tff');
}
```